# Enumerating IEnumerable in EF6 in debugger issues "Children could not be evaluated" error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I have a new ASP.NET MVC 5 project and am attempting to query a code first database through a IdentityDbContext.

If I query a particular DbSet and insert a breakpoint, attempting to read the contents of the IEnumerable will result in VS 2013 telling me that the children could not be evaluated.

I did not have this issue in EF5 / MVC 4.

Has something changed as to make evaluating IQueryables and the like impossible in the debugger in EF6?

Thanks

Comment: could this be a change to lazy loading. I use Quick view or LINQPad in such a situation.

Comment: I suppose it could be! I do have LinqPad - how would you use it in this context?

Comment: Set up the connection in LINQPad and then copy the code snippet from your code with the dbContext and run it.

Comment: Let me know if it works and I'll ad it as an answer. Thanks

Comment: Linqpad will run the code and dump the contents of the variable which I suppose is a workaround but I'm still not sure why the debugger chokes with IQueryables in EF6 now :-\

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is how it works for now, hopefully it will get fixed at some point, but for now you have to "ToList()" stuff via the watch windows. Urgh!

> EF Team Triage: The root cause behind this is an external issue with Lazy. We did discuss creating our own re-implementation of Lazy to workaround the issue but at this stage it doesn't seem to justify the effort. If we see more complaints about this in the future we will reconsider.
>
> **> The best workaround is to add a ToList() or similar (either in the
>   code or as a Watch) to see the results.**

http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/1898

Comment: consider this a complaint.

Comment: When I add ToList() via the watch window I get the following error in the Watch value:
  The function evaluation requires all threads to run.
???