# Children could not be evaluated (null pointer exception)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, list, children

I have problem and i dont why. I usually use same code structure in other classes and first seen like this error.

i have this code in my dataacces class

```
 public static IQueryable<EgmCode> RetrieveRegistryVehicleTypeEgmCodes()
        {
            return BaseRepository.RetrieveAll<EgmCode>().Where(x => x.IsRegistryVehicleType == 1);
        }
```

and i'm calling this method in my ProductService like this

```
 public static List<EgmCode> RetrieveRegistryVehicleTypeEgmCodes()
        {
            return EgmCodeRepository.RetrieveRegistryVehicleTypeEgmCodes().ToList();
        }

        .....

 Model.EgmCodes = ProductService.RetrieveRegistryVehicleTypeEgmCodes().ToList();
```

in Database there are 5 records but entity framework giving this error("Children could not be evaluated"). Image link is below

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4KpU0TF_l3XaU0wc1RBcXlZT2c/view?usp=sharing

Comment: possible duplicate of [Enumerating IEnumerable in EF6 in debugger issues "Children could not be evaluated" error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19631812/enumerating-ienumerable-in-ef6-in-debugger-issues-children-could-not-be-evaluat)

Comment: It doesn't necessarily look like an error, just the debugger saying that it can't iterate the children of the inspected property. Are you getting an actual exception somewhere?

Comment: i am having null pointer exception if i press f5 or f10 .